# Have a canvas on an undecorated JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe

I'm working with canvases in my JFrame, but when I set the frame to Undecorated the canvas stops showing itself. Is there a loop-around I'm missing or is there a better way of setting the frame to undecorated than using `FrameName.setUndecorated(true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you did something like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(new Canvas() );
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

now it looks like nothing is shown, right?

well, if you haven't done any custom draw operations yet it may SEEM as nothings happens, but if you start drawing, the content should be visible;

try as example, to set the background and tell me if it works ^^

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.setBackGround(Color.GREEN);
canvas.setOpaque(true); //i'm not sure if canvas is not transparent, i should read api first ^^
frame.add(canvas);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks man, I found my problem in that I would set the frame to visible and undecorated before even adding the canvas to it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: forgot to do that, sorry!

Comment: nice - thanks a lot! i hope i can provide further help!